# Java8 check if a given integer is present in Integer[] array

Tags: java-8

I have a Integer array as follows.

```
Integer[] nums = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
Integer inputNum = 3;
```

I would like to check if 3 is present here.

Was trying to use the below code, but it doesnt accpet, Integer[].

```
IntStream.of(nums).anyMatch(num -> num == inputNum);
```

> IntStream java.util.stream.IntStream.of(int... values)

Is there any better approach with Java 8?

Comment: Obviously `num==num` will match everything in the stream.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Updated.

Comment: With an `Integer[]` I reckon `Arrays.asList(nums).contains(inputNum)` is actually neater and likely more performant. This is a case of "when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have an `Integer[]` therefore you can utilise `Stream.of` instead of `IntStream.of`.

`IntStream.of` only takes primitive integers whereas `Stream.of` is used for reference types.

```
boolean isPresent = Stream.of(nums).anyMatch(num -> Objects.equals(num, inputNum));
```

but I prefer to use `Arrays.stream` in this case instead of the `XXX.of` methods as in the ideal world you should only use them when you're going to provide explicit values.

```
boolean isPresent = Arrays.stream(nums).anyMatch(num -> Objects.equals(num, inputNum));
```

Comment: As a said above, I think `Arrays.asList(nums).contains(inputNum)` is not only shorter but clearer in intent.

Comment: @BoristheSpider agreed, it's just that OP is asking for a java-8 solution.

Comment: Indeed. But I think that the request for a Java 8 solution is misguided in this case - rule of cool...

Comment: @user1578872 not sure, you'll have to run some tests.

Comment: @user1578872 for the given scenario I wouldn't worry about performance. pick whichever is more readable to you. Boris has provided a good and short solution which reads like problem statement and is shorter ;)

Comment: If you know that your input array will always be sorted, you could use Arrays.binarySearch();

Comment: As @Vink says (and you should really think about this), a binary search might be the best thing to do here - but measuring is required. Also, unless you have a specific target time-wise, don't worry about it, use whatever you can read more easily.

Comment: When you know that the `inputNum` is not `null`, you can use `.anyMatch(inputNum::equals)`. Otherwise, I’d use `.anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(inputNum))`, which pre-checks whether the argument is `null`, to return the equivalent of either, `inputNum::equals` or `Objects::isNull`. In contrast, `Objects.equals` effectively repeats the check for `null` for every element.